# Creating alias to domain name with /etc/hosts

Tags: networking, hostname, hosts

I have a domain setup to point to my LAN's external IP using dynamic DNS, because my external IP address changes frequently. However, I want to create an alias to this host, so I can access it with `home`. So I appended the following to my `/etc/hosts`:

`example.com home`

However, it doesn’t seem to like the domain name. If I change it to an IP:

`0.0.0.0 home`

then it works, but of course this defeats the purpose of dynamic DNS!

Is this possible?

Comment: Why does your external IP change frequently? Is this your provider internet-IP that gets assigned to you from a pool?

Comment: Yes, it is. I don't know why, my ISP just seem to change it sometimes!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The file `/etc/hosts` contains IP addresses and host names only. You cannot alias the string "home" in the way that you want by this method.

If you were running your own DNS server you'd be able to add a `CNAME` record to make `home.example.com` an alias for `domain.example`, but otherwise you're out of luck.

The best thing you could do is use the same DNS client to update a fully-qualified name.

Answer (score 4):

As stated, `/etc/hosts` was not intended to provide alias (`CNAME`) ability for name to IP lookups. While setting up a proper DNS server and configuring the `CNAME` there would definitely be an always-accurate way to resolve `home` to the IP of `example.com`, it is a bit more involving than a simple alias.

The change itself can be automated quite easily to a single line within a script:

```
sudo sed -i "s/.* home/$(dig +short domain.com|tail -1) home/" /etc/hosts
```

If you already have a means of detecting an IP change, this could easily be appended to that process. Otherwise, a brute force method of just scheduling an overwrite every `x` period could be set up with a simple cron job.

References:

- [How can I resolve a hostname to an IP address in a Bash script?](https://linuxhint.com/resolve_hostname_ip_address_bash_script/)
- [Sed: Find and Replace The Whole Line [ Regex ] - nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-sed-match-replace-the-entire-line-command/)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle the situation you describe is to set your DNS Search Domain to `domain.com`.

Also, create a DNS Record so that `home.domain.com` points to `domain.com`.

Your home router should allow you to set the DHCP Search Domain. Most mobile devices also allow for this.

Then you'll be able to directly:

```
ping home
```

And it should ping `home.domain.com`.

The exact way that you set the Search Domain will very slightly by device, but almost every device will allow you to set the search domain...

Then you don't have to limit yourself to `home`... You'll also be pinging `printer`, `phone` and maybe even `fridge` without bothering with fully qualified domain names...

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me as if you should register to DYNDNS or something like that.

If you really want to use /etc/hosts you have to monitor your IP. As soon as it changes:

- Change the entry in /etc/hosts
- Reload the hosts-cache
- Keep monitoring

**Update**
If you are using `dhcpcd` you can use the "-c" option for a script that changes your /etc/hosts-entry an then reloads the host-cache.

This depends on the capabilities of your dhcp-client.

Comment: I’ve registered to no-ip, which provides a similar service to DYNDNS I believe (I couldn't see to sign up on the DYNDNS homepage!)

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh so you can use the name you registered on no-ip! I do not see your reason to do this via /etc/hosts.

Comment: Quite simply it is because I’m lazy! Typing `home` is quite a few keystrokes less than `oliverjash.no-ip.org`

Comment: have you thought of aliases within you shell, or setting your domain search list in /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: @mdpc I did not ask the question. But an alias within the shell will propably not work within the browser. He could use a local proxy with a rewrite-rule, though...

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh I just checked the man-page of dhcpcd - there is probably a very simple solution there (did not test it).

Comment: @Nils can you elaborate about this a bit more?