# short name a domain name

Tags: dns, ip, dynamic-dns

I have a DDNS service with noip.com, but the link I have is so hard to remember.
It's working, I can resolve it using `resolveip link` and I get the current IP of the router.
I tried to use /etc/hosts but it didn't work, it requires that I put an IP.

How can I give a short name to the DDSN link I have.
for example `ping name` , so the system would resolve name for the DDNS link.

I wonder if NetworkManager or ip addr can help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand. The whole point of noip.com is to have a name that is easy to remember. Can't you just pick a better name? Are you just looking for something like storing the name in a variable and then doing `ping "$name"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating alias to domain name with /etc/hosts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58925/creating-alias-to-domain-name-with-etc-hosts)

Comment: Yes, but I accepted a random-generated one, and that was my fault.
Anyway it'd be great if I learn how to do that.

And as an answer to your question, I don't know anything about variables, it may work but I'm not sure... Can you show me how, please? 

As I said, I use /etc/hosts for static IPs, but it doesn't work for DNS domain name.

Comment: @xhienne not really, I don't run my own DNS server, I'm using openDNS, but I have DDNS to point me to Dynamic IP address node that I always need access to.

I'm looking into linux variables now as terdon mentioned them, I will update if I have any success with that.

Comment: @terdon it seems variables are for system/local environment like shell home folder etc...

I don't think they are useful for DNS stuff.

Maybe ip addr , dnsmasq or some other networking service?!
All I need is to call that long name as short one...
Thanks

Comment: @Abd In the other question, OP has a domain on DDNS and wants to use a short name like `home` instead. This is exactly what you want if I understand your question correctly. So, the answers are the same here and there.

Comment: "_ I accepted a random-generated one_" - why not discard that one and get a fresh one that you define?

Comment: See also [Can I create a user-specific hosts file to complement /etc/hosts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104511)

Comment: @ChrisDavies I'm on free account, I don't know if they allow me to change it.
being cheap has it's negatives

Comment: It's trivial to change one. I've literally just created an account to try this. Delete the hostname you've got and then add your own preferred one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the address in a variable and then you can ping that:

```
$ foo=unix.stackexchange.com
$ ping "$foo"
PING unix.stackexchange.com (104.18.43.226) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 104.18.43.226 (104.18.43.226): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=5.12 ms
64 bytes from 104.18.43.226 (104.18.43.226): icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=10.5 ms
64 bytes from 104.18.43.226 (104.18.43.226): icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=8.05 ms
^C
--- unix.stackexchange.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.120/7.901/10.532/2.212 ms
```

To make it permanent, edit your `~/.profile` file (or `~/.bash_profile` if that file exists and you are using `bash`) and add this line (of course, change `foo` to whatever you want your variable to be called and change the URL to the name of your server):

```
export foo=unix.stackexchange.com
```

Now, from the next time you log in, you will be able to run `ping "$foo"` to ping, or `echo "$foo"` to print it out etc.

Comment: it worked :D
I was thinking I must use some advanced DNS technique